# How to use WMTS url service in my android map application as basemap?

Tags: google-maps-api, android, wmts

I am building a android map application and i want to use as basemap some wmts url services of our country.

How can i implement this and get layers from WMTS url services as TileOverlay to google map android api?
Example:

Wmts source:
**http://geoportal.asig.gov.al:85/utm34n/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml**

the tileoverlay url inside xml configuration:

**http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:85/utm34n/ortofoto/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.jpg**

but Google Map Android Api needed this configuration of url:

**http://my.image.server/images/x/y/z.png**

x- x coordinate ( start from 0 to maxwidth)
y- y coordinate ( start from 0 to maxheight)
z- Zoom

refer to documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay

How can I format the url from the wmts service ResourceURL( from WMTSCapabilities.xml), to integrate inside google map android api?

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far so that we can see where to help

Comment: How far have you managed to progress with this? I have similar capabilities xml defining wmts but don't know how to approach this..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already found solution but anyway.
Like in the documentation is:
    /* Define the URL pattern for the tile images */
    String s = String.format("http://my.image.server/images/%d/%d/%d.png",
        zoom, x, y);

Change the path to this and then: tilematrix=zoom, tilecol=x and tilerow=y

String s = String.format("http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:85/utm34n/ortofoto/UTM34N/%d/%d/%d.jpg",zoom,x,y)

Answer (score 0):

**Using esri map you can call wmts services**

```
WmtsService wmtsService = new WmtsService(getString(R.string.wmts_url));
wmtsService.addDoneLoadingListener(() -> {
  if (wmtsService.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
    // get service info
    WmtsServiceInfo wmtsServiceInfo = wmtsService.getServiceInfo();
    // get the first layer id
    List<WmtsLayerInfo> layerInfoList = wmtsServiceInfo.getLayerInfos();
    // create WMTS layer from layer info
    WmtsLayer wmtsLayer = new WmtsLayer(layerInfoList.get(0));
    // set the basemap of the map with WMTS layer
    map.setBasemap(new Basemap(wmtsLayer));
  } else {
    String error = "Error loading WMTS Service: " + wmtsService.getLoadError();
    Log.e(TAG, error);
    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});wmtsService.loadAsync();
```